# How do I prove that in any ordered field if $x\ne 0$ then $x^2>0$?

Tags: ordered-fields

I'm asked to prove

> In any ordered field if $x\ne 0$ then $x^2>0$?

I thought of doing separate cases for $x>0$ and $x<0$ but I cannot prove that for any $a,b>0$ in an ordered field, $ab>0$ and for $a<0$ in an ordered field $-a>0$. If I'm able to prove this assertion then I think I can prove the main problem.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2\neq0$?

Comment: If $x>0$ , then multiplying with $x$ gives $x^2>0$. If $x<0$, we get $x^2>0$ again since multiplying with a negative number turns "<" to ">". Hence $x^2=0$ can only hold if $x=0$.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino sorry I fixed it.

Comment: @Peter but in any arbitrary ordered field how can I say "multiplying with negative numbers"? Or how can I even say that for "$x>0$ multiplying with $x$ gives $x^2>0$"? Don't I have to prove these?

Comment: @Itachi This is a property every order has.

Comment: @Peter can you suggest me some article or pdf or anything on that? I don't know about it yet.

Comment: @Peter I found it. No need to for you to search for me now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2$ cannot be $=0$ because there are no zero-divisors. If $x<0$ then $-x>0$ and $(-x)x<0$, that is $-x^2<0$, so $x^2>0$. If $x>0$ then $x^2=x*x>0$.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually I was missing a big chunk that in any ordered field $x,y>0 \implies xy>0$. That's why I had to go through this trouble.